# Syntax Highlighting library in ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, syntax-highlighting

I let user enter some code in my Flex3 (Flash 10) app and I want to do syntax highlighting.

Is there any open-source library that would help me?

I'll need a Lua syntax support, but I can add it myself if library has a resonable interface to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update on 21 Jan, 2009:

Check out [Anirudh's port of google-code-prettify to ActionScript3](http://code.google.com/p/as3syntaxhighlight/), it has a very good example app as well.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this wasn't even feasible till now.

With the new [Flash Text Engine](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Gumbo+Text+Primitives), maybe such text-based features will start showing up, and hopefully open source libraries that work like the [FlashEff](http://www.flasheff.com) library.

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to do syntax highlighting, I found a example which works
http://labs.searchcoders.com/text/

You will need to take their actionscript code and when people change the text in your text area then you will need to re-draw the syntax highlighting.

Basically I am doing this as I'm making my own IDE/Language in FLEX.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://www.flashtexteditor.com/ftf/
or this:
http://www.matthijskamstra.nl/blog/index.php/2008/06/04/actionscript-syntax-highlighting/