# Is there a textArea for flex, which supports html-text with css formatting?

Tags: html, css, apache-flex

I would like create a text area with code highlighting in flex. Is there an advanced textArea witch suports css for real. For example:

```
myHtmltext:String = '<span class="keyword"> #include </span>';

myTextArea:TextArea = new TextArea();

myTextArea.htmlText = myHtmltext;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366528/syntax-highlighting-library-in-actionscript

Answer (score 2):

You have to extend the TextArea to make it accept the styles via StyleManager. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289635/json-as-html-data-in-flex-hyperlink-rollovers/2290197#2290197) for more info. It discusses the Text component, but the principle is the same.

Comment: I tried to highlight the text as mentioned in that discussion... by changing text color with <font color="#ffffff">code</font> but I want to create "themes" so css would be the real solution.