# Is there any text highlighter component for Flex / AIR / ActionScript 3.0?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, text-editor

I need a rich text editor component (like [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/)) for a project made in **Flex** and **ActionScript 3.0**.

Is there any one out there?
If not, is there a way to run Scintilla inside Flash (AIR runtime)?

---

**Edit:**

Reading a answer I understood that the question is ambiguous.
To make it clear, I don't want a WYSIWYG. I need a text editor to make a IDE like environment.
Examples are Notepad++, Eclipse, FlashDevelop and such. (Notepad++ and FlashDevelop uses Scintilla component, as far as I know).
This is the kind of editor that I want.

---

**Edit:**

> @NemoStein I honestly don't understand what specific features you're looking for. – www.Flextras.com

Right, so I'll try to explain in another way:
Suppose that you are trying to build an IDE.
This IDE will cover an language, let's say, C++.
Your final user expects **highlighting**, **code completion**, a **gutter** with **line numbers**, maybe a way to **search through code** and such features.

Scintilla is a component (a .dll, I think, but I never used it, actually) that you can embed in your application that do exactly that.

I don't need any code completion (although this could be a huge bonus), but I need text highlighting.

As I said before, Scintilla do everything that I want to, and much more, but I didn't find any article, tutorial, paper or anything about running it inside ActionScript.

If this doesn't make any sense, please, let me know.
I'll try my best to explain. =D

Comment: this one is the built-in one: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_10.html. but it's kind of basic ... don't know if it's enough

Comment: Thanks, @pkyeck, but this isn't what I need. Take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time searching, Google led my to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366528/syntax-highlighting-library-in-actionscript) and, subsequently, to this two links:

- [SearchCoders/text](http://labs.searchcoders.com/text/)
- [as3syntaxhighlight](http://code.google.com/p/as3syntaxhighlight/)

I haven't tried any yet, but both seems to do the job.
I'll take the first one, as it appears to be (although old) much more mature and flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Flex RichTextEditor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d89.html).

Comment: Thanks, @www.Flextras.com , but this isn't what I need. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: @NemoStein I honestly don't understand what specific features you're looking for.